# How to delete a url in each string from a dataset

Tags: regex, python-2.7, twitter

I have a dataset in which 1 column has the tweets and other column has labels for the tweets. My problem is I want the html links present in the tweets to be removed for example

RT @AmDiabetesAssn: Know whatâ€™s scary? These #diabetes statistics. Spread awareness this November for #DiabetesMonth! http://t.co/qIiiSc4ozZ

I have a tweet as given above i want to remove(http://t.co/qIiiSc4ozZ) and want the output in this way, for all the strings.

RT @AmDiabetesAssn: Know whatâ€™s scary? These #diabetes statistics. Spread awareness this November for #DiabetesMonth!

I have seen many examples and tried those but couldn't get the desired result. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, which should work for any links that don't have spaces in them:

```
for tweet in tweets:
  print re.sub(r'http://\S+\s?','',tweet)
```

I assume here that you've got a bunch of strings in the `tweets` array that represent the first column that you described above (also that you want them printed). You should be able to modify to suit the iteration pattern you're using.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer                                               This is the error which i get when i run the code which u have given

Comment: Sry Doug I got it. Thanks for your quick reply. You were really helpful

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Good luck.